# Commit transaction from outside the session

Tags: postgresql, session, transactions, commit

Is there any function in postgres that could commit hanging transaction in another session?
For instance somebody startet session and began transaction then forgotten about commit and I would like to commit this transaction from my session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do that in PostreSQL or any other RDBMS for that matter. If you have DBA access to your database, you could kill the session whose commit has not been made (and the transaction will be rollbacked).